# SQL Select Distinct with Conditional

Tags: sql, mysql

Table1 has columns (id, a, b, c, group).  There are several rows that have the same group, but id is always unique.  I would like to SELECT group,a,b FROM Table1 WHERE the group is distinct.  However, I would like the returned data to be from the row with the greatest id for that group.

Thus, if we have the rows

```
(id=10, a=6, b=40, c=3, group=14)  
(id=5, a=21, b=45, c=31, group=230)  
(id=4, a=42, b=65, c=2, group=230)
```

I would like to return these 2 rows:

```
[group=14, a=6,b=40] and   
[group=230, a=21,b=45] (because id=5 > id=4)
```

Is there a simple SELECT statement to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a self join or an inner-select. Here's inner select:

```
select `group`, a, b from Table1 AS T1
   where id=(select max(id) from Table1 AS T2 where T1.`group` = T2.`group`)
```

And self-join method:

```
select T1.`group`, T2.a, T2.b from
   (select max(id) as id,`group` from Table1 group by `group`) T1
   join Table1 as T2 on T1.id=T2.id
```

Comment: I think self-join will be much faster than correlated subquery.

Comment: I totally agree, but it's informative to show both, plus I can type the first faster. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I should have mentioned that my table is gigantic. Many of the other provided solutions hung, despite the fact that they appear to be valid.  The self-join example you provided worked very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select grp, a, b
  from table1 where id in
    (select max(id) from table1 group by grp)
```

Answer (score 1):

2 selects, your inner select gets:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM YourTable GROUP BY [GROUP]
```

Your outer select joins to this table.

Think about it logically, the inner select gets a sub set of the data you need.
The outer select inner joins to this subset and can get further data.

```
SELECT [group], a, b FROM YourTable INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM YourTable GROUP BY [GROUP]) t
ON t.id = YourTable.id
```

Comment: Stackoverflow needs to implement a feature to see who down voted you, because there is NO reason for this!

Comment: I didn't, but you'd need an alias on the MAX(id) column in order to join on it

Comment: Neither did I, but in `MySQL` reserved words should be enclosed in backticks, not square brackets.

Comment: @Quassnoi, syntax does not matter theory does.  This works in SQL Server, apply the theory to mySQL and it works.  That is just like a programming language, a class is a class, whether it is vb.net, c# or PHP.  Everyone needs to stop being so concrete.

Comment: @Mark - it certainly helps to know who did it so you can ask why.  The solution is correct...the downvoting wasn't.  So it helps to explain WHY it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  mi.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT grouper
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable mi
ON      mi.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mo
        WHERE   mo.grouper = md.grouper
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

If your table is `MyISAM` *or* `id` is not a `PRIMARY KEY`, then make sure you have a composite index on `(grouper, id)`.

If your table is `InnoDB` and `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, then a simple index on `grouper` will suffice (`id`, being a `PRIMARY KEY`, will be implictly included).

This will use an `INDEX FOR GROUP-BY` to build the list of distinct groupers, and for each grouper it will use the index access to find the maximal `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it in mysql. But the following code will work for MsSQL...

> ```
> SELECT Y.* FROM
> (
>     SELECT DISTINCT [group], MAX(id) ID
>     FROM Table1
>     GROUP BY [group]
>  ) X
> INNER JOIN Table1 Y ON X.ID=Table1.ID
> ```